# Being able to save (multiple) changes without affecting database - structural issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, data-structures, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm developing a business web application which will maintain a database with several tables. One of the requirements are that one should be able to "save your work" without affecting the database and then later pick it up and continue working. Multiple "savings" must be supported.

This administration tool will be developed in ASP.NET MVC4 or Microsoft's LightSwitch, I haven't decided yet.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to solve this structurally, are there any known techniques to this problem? I need help by someone to point me in the right direction, I'm stuck here..

**EDIT:** I'll try to explain further with a scenario

1. I make a change to one row and save, but the change should only be visible to me (not affect the main database).
2. I realize the change in 1. is bad and choose to start over with changing the data in the same row, I also make a change to another row. I save these changes (but only for me)
3. Now I have two savings (from step 1 and 2), I change my mind and the changes made in 1. is correct and I open that "savefile" and commit the changes to main databse. I'll then delete the "savefile" from step 2.

Hope that makes the situation more clear.

Thanks

Comment: your question not clear to me: save without persisting ?? Are we talking of an offline/disconnected mode, of tracking changes, versionning... or anything else ?

Comment: Added a scenario that might explain it abit better. Sorry for being unclear. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: well, from here it seems you'are trying to build an collaborative tool with versioning... very large subject. I may only suggest you to search, try and get back here with more scoped questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that I can think of is to let the database do the work for you.

You could:

1. Just add some type of a "status" column ("committed", "uncommitted" etc) to the table, & filter out any "uncommitted" records in any grid that displays "real" data. You can then also filter
   a different way in your editing grid, that only shows you
   "uncommitted" records, or if you could save an ID instead of a status, if you
   only want to see your own records.
2. Add another table to hold the uncommitted records, rather than
   "pollute" the actual table with extra columns.

Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I didn't think of that! Doing this I don't need to save the "uncommited" data anywhere else as I first thought, which easy would get confusing.

I did some reading just now and it seems Wordpress uses this same technique for post revisions. Great, thanks alot!

Comment: and if you want to track the pending changes per user, you'll have to store this data too ...

Answer (score 0):

if you are really going to build a transactional type version control system, then you have  a huge job ahead.

look at some popular tools like SVN and see the level of complication and features they support.

Rolling back a partial transaction inside a database - especially one with constraints and triggers will be very difficult.  almost everything would run into an issue somewhere.

you may also consider storing uncommitted transactions outside the database - like in some local XML structure - then committing the components only once when desired.

either way, the interface for finding all the records and determining which ones to do what with will be a challenge - nevermind the original application.